# Is Apache Cassandra Quickstart broken?

Tags: cassandra, docker

I'm following the steps in the current (2023-03-13) Cassandra [quickstart](https://cassandra.apache.org/_/quickstart.html):

STEP 1: GET CASSANDRA USING DOCKER

```
docker pull cassandra:latest
```

STEP 2: START CASSANDRA

```shell
docker network create cassandra
docker run --rm -d --name cassandra --hostname cassandra --network cassandra \
 cassandra
```

STEP 3: CREATE FILES

Created the file `data.cql` with the CQL script:

```
-- Create a keyspace
CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS store 
 WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : '1' };

-- Create a table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS store.shopping_cart (
userid text PRIMARY KEY,
item_count int,
last_update_timestamp timestamp
);

-- Insert some data
INSERT INTO store.shopping_cart
(userid, item_count, last_update_timestamp)
VALUES ('9876', 2, toTimeStamp(now()));
INSERT INTO store.shopping_cart
(userid, item_count, last_update_timestamp)
VALUES ('1234', 5, toTimeStamp(now()));
```

Step 4:

```shell
docker run --rm --network cassandra -v "$(pwd)/data.cql:/scripts/data.cql" \
-e CQLSH_HOST=cassandra -e CQLSH_PORT=9042 -e CQLVERSION=3.4.5 \
 nuvo/docker-cqlsh
```

STEP 4: LOAD DATA WITH CQLSH
is failing with error:

```
"Can't establish connection, will retry again in 5 sconds
Failed to connect to cassandra at cassandra:9042"
```

I'm on Windows 10, with Docker Desktop installed as administrator, running the commands on PowerShell 7.3.3

Is there a known workaround for this issue?

Comment: Good point mustaccio. I've rephrased my question in the form of an actual question. Do you think it's understandable now?

Comment: Yes it is. But its preferable that you post the information here, rather than relying on a link.

Comment: Thanks Rohit, I've edited the question to include the steps.

Comment: And I have upvoted it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does seem to be broken, because the world has moved on.

If you simply run

```shell
docker run --network cassandra -ti \
-e CQLSH_HOST=cassandra -e CQLSH_PORT=9042 -e CQLVERSION=3.4.5 \
nuvo/docker-cqlsh cqlsh
```

you'll get

> Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'172.18.0.2': ProtocolError("cql_version '3.3.1' is not supported by remote (w/ native protocol). Supported versions: [u'3.4.6']",)})

Apparently, as of today the image "cassandra:latest" wants the CQL version 3.4.6, while the tutorial uses version 3.4.5. So, change the `-e CQLVERSION` value to 3.4.6 and adjust the subsequent steps accordingly.